# Can you divide by xvw in css?

Tags: css

I want my div box to grow vertically as the window shrinks horizontally.

Then I found out about the calc() function in css and tried the following:

```
.fancyBox {
    height: calc(1000 / 1vw);
}
```

so in theory, if the window is 1920px wide then the height should be ~52px and if the window is 1024px wide then the height should be ~98px

However, the height attribute gets ignored and doesn't show up in the browsers inspector (I'm testing with firefox). Should this work? Am I mucking up the syntax? Any other way to do it(in just CSS that is)?

EDIT: the expected result is height = (1000 / (0.01 * < window width >))px

Comment: Is the element `display: block` or `inline-block`? Have you tried using the vendor prefix (which the [MDN documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/calc) seems to suggest is necessary)?

Comment: Can you explain your expected relation about `height` and `vw`? I don't quite get it by your formula.

Answer (score 0):

I think the VW or VH value needs to come first, because this seems to work:

```
height:  calc(1vw/2);
```

Comment: it does but i need an inverse relationship between height of the container and width of the view